# Difference between the returned [object HTMLCollection] and [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I am wondering what is the difference between the returned **[object HTMLCollection]** from `document.getElementsByClassName` and **[object HTMLDivElement]** from `document.querySelector`

Does **[object HTMLCollection]** means that we are performing a "wider" DOM scanning and will return a collection of elements if exists? Thats why it returns HTML Collection rather than Element?

However, this question came into mind as `ReactDOM.render` didn't accept the returned **[object HTMLCollection]** to be used as a second parameter.

Cheers.

Comment: Just look at the name of the `getElementsByClassName()` function: it is talking about element**s**, plural.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` - notice *element`s`*, which is why we get a Collection. Even `document.querySelectorAll` will return a Colleciton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `HTMLCollection` is a group of elements. It may contain 0 or more elements.

An `HTMLDivElement` is a single Element

---

`document.getElementsByClassName('x')` is more like `document.querySelectorAll('.x')` because each will return a group.

`document.querySelector` will only return a single element

Comment: Note that an `HTMLCollection` can contain a single element, or contain no elements (possibilities which I think strain the definition of "group"), but even then it must still be treated as a list rather than as a single item.